# When recalling a JPanel instance creating method, the panel overlaps the previous one. How can I stop this?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

Probably an easy fix, but Would be wonderful if someone can help me through this!

SO I have a method which creates a panel and also adds it to the `JFrame`.

The problem is, I want to keep recalling the method with slightly different text.

Although it does recall, it creates a new instance of it overtop of the previous one instead of replacing it.

```
}public void lyricPrinter(){

    System.out.println(lyrics);
    JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea(lyrics);
    textarea.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    textarea.setEditable(false);
    //JLabel textarea = new JLabel("not sure what this is...");
    //textarea.setText("<html>"+lyrics+"</html>");

    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane (textarea,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    //GUI.frame.remove(scroll);
    GUI.frame.add(scroll);
    GUI.frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Seems you need to change text in your textarea, is it right?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I assume you can simply remove the old panel using Container's remove(Component c) method, and then add the new panel using Container's add(Component c) method. You can read [Container's API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html) for more information.

Comment: @WorldBright  *"I assume you can simply.."*  Please stop assuming.  Not only is there more to it than that, but the problem night better be solved using a `CardLayout` or simply replacing the content or model of the component in question.

Comment: @WorldBright I've tried that. This might work if I had added it onto a  seperate panel, but since I add the text directly to the frame, if I try removing it it doesn't give me an option since it doesn't exsist before the program is actually running.

Comment: I've made a messy fix, would still love a better alternative than this..
ever time I call this method, I removeAll() components from the jframe, and then re-add the ones I want directly after.
I know there's got to be a better way than this but it works.

Comment: *" I know there's got to be a better way than this"*  Certainly there is.  Where is that MCVE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time the method runs, you are creating a new panel. In order to prevent this, you need to create only 1 instance of Panel Class, so that when the method runs, work will be done on same panel.

1-) Define Panel instance as local variable int your class.
2-) Instantiate the Panel in your "lyricPrinter" Method
3-) Immediately After, destroy the panel components using .removeAll()

It should work.

For your example;

```
JScrollPane scroll; //-->> somewhere in your class
public void lyricPrinter(){

    System.out.println(lyrics);
    JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea(lyrics);
    textarea.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    textarea.setEditable(false);
//JLabel textarea = new JLabel("not sure what this is...");
//textarea.setText("<html>"+lyrics+"</html>");

 **scroll = new JScrollPane (textarea,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
scroll.removeAll();**


//GUI.frame.remove(scroll);
GUI.frame.add(scroll);
GUI.frame.setVisible(true);
```